# How to get a single public static IP address to use from multiple locations?

Tags: networking, macos, ip

For development work I need to connect to my client's AWS server from multiple locations. But the server is only accessible from allowed IPs. As I connect through different networks I got different IPs. So I need a static IP or any other solution, so regardless the location I can connect with the same IP. I'll ask my client to allow that single IP address.

Answer (score 2):

You could get a cheap VPS somewhere (Google for "cheap VPS") with a static IP (all of them) and then use either a VPN solution to connect to the VPS or use it as a stepping stone box to connect to the AWS servers.

Even a small VPS (128MB) would be enough for this use case (it only needs to forward your SSH/RDP), so you could be done for USD 1 per month.